# Ansible, AWS, other host based on tag

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ansible

I am creating Ansible playbooks which create our system's infrastructure in AWS. Obviously dynamic inventories using ec2.py are involved.

I first create a utility server, then a web server, and I have a separate playbook for each of these. I have files on the web server which need to have the private ip of the utility server added using a template.

What's the best way to retrieve the private ip of the utility server for use in the web server's playbook?

Comment: To clarify, I'd like to solve this problem with Ansible playbooks.

Comment: At least in Ansible 1.9, the second playbook can gather facts and identify the first utility server via tags (and most of its pertinent values, including private ips afaik). If you set a new tag with key-value Type-utility, ec2.py will automatically generate a group tag_Type_utility which you can refer to and yank the private ip out of. I'll look into it when I wake up tomorrow and post an answer, if no one beats me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were three problems:

1. You need information from another server to use in the current
   server you're configuring.
2. The other server you need information from is hosted in AWS.
3. The other server you need to access information about has a variable name.

The solution to **3** is to specify the variable in the command line using extra-vars like so: **ansible-playbook -i ./ec2.py --extra-vars "chaos=test" aws_playground.yaml**

The solution to **2** is to find the hostname you need from the hostvars' groups variable. When combined with 3 above, you want something like: **- debug: var=hostvars[groups['tag_Name_'+chaos+'_util'][0]].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0]**

The solution to **1** is to first collect facts from the other server before working on the server you're configuring. Below is a playbook collecting all this in one place:

---

```
# Called like: ansible-playbook -i ./ec2.py --extra-vars "chaos=test" aws_playground.yaml
- name: Collect our facts on util
  hosts: "tag_Name_{{ chaos }}_util"
  tasks: [ ]

- name: Set up a web server
  hosts: "tag_Name_{{ chaos }}_web"
  tasks:
   - debug: var=hostvars[groups['tag_Name_'+chaos+'_util'][0]].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The IPs of the servers are part of the discoverable facts about the hosts. These facts are retrieved automatically when you run a playbook, unless you explicitly disable `gather_facts`.

And even then, you can explicitly use the [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html) module to collect facts.

This values can then be used in the next tasks.

As an example:

```
$ ansible -c local -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_*address*' localhost                                                                              
127.0.0.1 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
            "172.17.0.1", 
            "192.168.122.1", 
            "192.168.0.12", 
            "172.18.0.1"
        ], 
        "ansible_all_ipv6_addresses": [
            "fe80::e8b5:946f:410b:aff5"
        ]
    }, 
    "changed": false
```

}

Comment: Yes, that answer is basic Ansible knowledge. My question is about accessing variables from ANOTHER server, not the current server's tasks. That is, while running the playbook to set up the web server, I need access to the ip address of the utility server, or the web server, or the cache server, for example.